# magento how to change session handler to memcached?

Tags: php, magento, session, memcached, magento2

I am a newbie at Magento and my server's default php session handler is memcached. I just installed Magento (version 2) and I keep getting error:

`open(localhost:11211/sess_qmnpedun2j0ie0jed9g8r08pd0, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory`

It is trying to use File Handler for Memcached sessions. How should I change it in Magento? Google-ing keeps telling me to go to local.xml and add the following:

```
<session_save><![CDATA[memcached]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://localhost:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path>
```

But the problem is that, I don't have `MAGENTO_DIR/app/etc/local.xml`, so I really don't know what to do.

I installed Magento2 through the links given in their [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2) page (command line install). The installation went successful and database and everything is created.

How can I change the session handler to use memcached in Magento-2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in Magento2 `local.xml` doesn't exist anymore and is replaced with `config.php` and `config.php` is in `.gitignore` (therefore you don't see it in GitHub!).

[Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/config-guide/config/config-php.html) you can find the instructions for creating your config.php file. At the bottom of the page under *Segment details* you can see how to define your personal configuration.

And [here](https://gist.github.com/Marko-M/93260137a9b914ed94c9) you can find an example of `config.php` file in Magento2.

For example regarding your case you need to add this structure to your `config.php` file:

```
    __/session
      |__/save
        |-- <files|db>
```

So I guess eventually you need to add something like this to your config.php:

```
      'session' => 
          array (
            'save' => 'memcache',
            'save_path' => 'tcp://localhost:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10'
           ),
```

*Don't forget to adjust the path (server and port) to match your environment.*

Comment: Thank you; for now I did db, I will do memcache in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

the support for memcache was dropped in magento 2.3.0.

I have created [plugin](https://connect20.aveo-trade.cz/Content_Cat:BuyPackage/details=1/extension=atconnect%2Fmagento-two-memcached-session) which allows use of memcache for session.

Documentation is available here: https://connect20.aveo-trade.cz/docs/user-guide-memcached-2.3.0.pdf